# Multitenant web application

Tags: struts2, multi-tenant

We would like to design multi-tenant web application. Searching through the forum they suggested we may achieve in Struts 2. Is it possible?

Do we have any other frameworks in Java we can achieve multi-tenancy in  web application?

Comment: If you highlight which feature in MT you want to build, it will be very helpful to guide you than taking on a broad topic

Comment: Multitenant web application in Struts2 is that possible? Do you find any solutions

Comment: It is possible by any framework as long as we have everything configurable at server side. We went ahead with play framework which we had experienced developers